# rsync complication on sync

Tags: linux, rsync, webserver

We have 2 Web Server node **Primary and secondary**, if the primary is down by any reason secondary will act as Prim.

Now if we talk about the codes we which is on both the host. we should be synchronizing it with actual primary data

**How do we sync those codes?**

I understand that `rsync` can sync all the thing from the Live server to the secondary. but what about those changed which have deleted some file or folder, from live server `rsync` should remove those from the secondary

As per my requirement can we use below rsync on my server. will this work

`rsync -avzhe ssh user@server.example.com:/var/www/ /var/www`

I tested this on my local system. no luck

```
[ar@test ~]$ rsync -avzhe /home/ar/avi/ /home/ar/red/
sending incremental file list
drwxrwxr-x        4096 2016/03/03 07:28:13 .

sent 51 bytes  received 12 bytes  126.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

**Solution**

`rsync -av --delete /home/ar/avi/ /home/ar/red/`

Comment: There seem to be nothing wrong. Verify the contents of the source directory on the server.

Comment: `rsync -avz /home/ar/avi/ /home/ar/red/` works fine.

Comment: `rsync -av --delete /home/ar/avi/ /home/ar/red/`  removes the file which is not present in the primary directory `/home/ar/avi/`

Comment: So what's the problem you're trying to solve? I'm sorry, but it's just not clear (to me).

Comment: I'm just asking that will this work on the live ENV.

Comment: Roaima previously it was giving me an error, and I wanted to check that is there any other way for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command works for me, it gets sync with the live server and deletes the file which were deleted from the live server.

`rsync -av --delete /home/ar/avi/ /home/ar/red/`