# Backup remote data as root

Tags: permissions, backup

I want to backup all data from a server before I do an Upgrade (Debian). Due to the fact, that there are many user accounts on the server, I thought I just copy all data with scp (`scp -r * user@backup-path`) as root to my backup disk. The problem now is that, if I do it like that I mess up the permissions of the files.

After coping the files look like this:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root        496 Mar  8 09:28 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root        336 Mar  8 09:27 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  154373124 Mar  8 09:24 file-5.cas
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  219287728 Mar  8 09:24 copy.tar
```

If I need to resore the data later this probably is a problem, isn't it?

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform `rsync` from the source to destination which will solve your permission.

`rsync -avzh ssh user@server.example.com:/your/source/ /destination/`

You can refer the below link for more details on `rsync`

[How to merge one directory into other?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267575/how-to-merge-one-directory-into-other/267580#267580)

[rsync complication on sync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267352/rsync-complication-on-sync)

Comment: I also thought about that, but what user do I use for my source because my source is the whole /home direcory?

Comment: you can perform it by root also.

Comment: and than the permissions are not messed up? Another question, what if something goes wrong and I have to restore everthing? Than there is an empty /home directory on the server and I want to copy the data from the backup-disk, how do I do that?

Comment: It won't work I get the following message: ```Unexpected remote arg: root@server:/home/
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1343) [sender=3.1.2]```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `tar`, with `-p` option (preserve permissions) before the transfert?

Comment: There is not enought disk space on the server to create a tar before the transfer (it is almost 1Tb)

Comment: and if you create all users before the transfert and make the `scp` with the good account ?

Comment: that probably works but it is an incredible amount of work because there are many users on the server