# how to rsync certain directory and files - problem

Tags: rsync

I have looked at previous posts but cannot get this working. I want to just rsync all the **server03** directories and **any** sub directories of them to a new server. I tried the following but it was picking up other directories other than **server03**. I guess I am missing something obvious. The structure is which I want to copy from is

/backup
/backup/day1
/backup/day1/xxxx
/backup/day1/server03
/backup/day1/yyyy

etc to

/backup/day31......

```
rsync --include="*/" --include="**server03/***" --exclude="*" -avzh root@fromserver:/backup /opt/backupfolder
```

Comment: refer this link `http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267352/rsync-complication-on-sync`, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run it on source ('fromserver'):

`find /backup -name server03 | while read i; do echo $i; mkdir -p /dest/dir/$i/; rsync -avzj --progress $i/ /dest/dir/$i/ ; done`

`mkdir` is needed if you want to keep structure like

```
/backup/day1/server03
/backup/day2/server03
/backup/day3/server03
```

etc